# strip hex to a single digit in string formating in python

Tags: python, string, format

I'm trying to convert RGB values to short hex format, I have the long version:

```
'#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g , b)
```

is it possible to get #fff instead of #ffffff without formatting the values one by one to take the first digits?

Edit:
my code doesn't require much accuracy in colors so it accepts a shortened version of color hex code that each color is represented by a single digit and the second digit is omitted.

any value from 0 to 15 is considered 0

any value from 16 to 31 is considered 1

and so on...

Comment: Your question is not clear (especially what you mean by "get #fff instead of #ffffff"). Please show some example inputs for `r`, `g`, and`b`, and the corresponding outputs. Choose a variety of inputs that will show what you mean without ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you have this code to output a rgb value on 24 bits

```
print('#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g , b))
```

if  you want to output a rgb value on 12 bits only when the value can be shortened

```
if (r % 17 == 0 and g % 17 == 0 and b % 17 == 0):
     print('#{:01x}{:01x}{:01x}'.format(r/17, g/17, b/17))
else:
     print('#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(r, g , b))
```

if you encode a mono chromatic color in 8 bits you have 256 values between 0 and 255 , so you have 255 intervals .

if you encode a mono chromatic color in 4 bits you have  16 values between 0 and 15  , so you have 15 intervals .

so 255 / 15 => 17

Comment: That doesn't work for color codes that cannot be shortened such as `r = g = b = 250` should return `fafafa` instead of `fff`

Comment: `print '#{:01x}{:01x}{:01x}'.format(r>>4, g >>4, b>>4)` give `#fff` with `r = g = b =  250 `

Comment: yes and that's wrong. When all the values are 250 the correct hex code is `#fafafa` but yours returns `#fff` because it assumes that whatever is passed in should always be shifted to the right by 4 digits instead of when it has repeated characters. So `#fff` represents `#ffffff` but not `#fafafa`.

Comment: i modified my answer

Comment: this got me an idea of the possible solution, now I have more questions:
 1- considering hex is base 16, shouldn't I divide the values by 16 instead of 17?
 2- what actually >>4 does? I can't figure it out reading the documentation.

Comment: the thing I'm trying to do is strip the second digits when the value is converted to hex. it is fine if `#fafafa` is converted to `#fff`